# Document initializes after form submit

Tags: javascript

I need to have an HTML document that can contain multiple input fields.
Starting with one field, a submit should create another input field as a copy of itself.
So I declared it with HTML code and wrote a function to append a copy of it to my div.
For testing purposes, I made a button to call my js function, too.

Now I'm confused as clicking the button will create a new field and pushing enter inside a field will initialize my HTML document, deleting previously created fields.

Can anybody figure out why?

Kind regards, Tommy

```
<button onclick="createRow()">New row</button>

    <div id="criteriaTableBody">
            <div class="tr" id="criteriaRow">
                <div class="td">
                    <form onsubmit="createRow()">
                        <input type="text" name="text" value="">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

<script>
function createRow() {

    var row = document.getElementById("criteriaRow");
    var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);

    document.getElementById("criteriaTableBody").appendChild(newRow);

}
</script>
```

Comment: The point is that submitting a form will load the target page of the form (the same eventually). What you need to implement is an AJAX function that will prevent the default submission, submit the form without reloading the page and in a callback add the new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your form submits. Forms are used to submit data to another page, so the entered data can be processed. You don't want this, instead you want to prevent the form from submitting using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```js
function createRow(event) { // Mind "event" here
  // Prevent form from submitting (reloading the page and deleting your "progress")
  event.preventDefault();

  var row = document.getElementById("criteriaRow");
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);

  document.getElementById("criteriaTableBody").appendChild(newRow);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="createRow(event)">New row</button> <!-- Pass event here! -->

<div id="criteriaTableBody">
  <div class="tr" id="criteriaRow">
    <div class="td">
      <form onsubmit="createRow(event)"> <!-- Pass event here! -->
        <input type="text" name="text" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I also recommend avoiding HTML attributes like `onclick`, `onsubmit`, etc. Use an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter will submit the form.

The submit event handler will run, then the contents of the form will be sent to the URL specified by the action (the current URL since there isn't an action).

This loads a new page.

Since there is no action, the new page is a brand new, unmodified by JS, copy of the current page.

---

Avoid intrinsic event attributes like `onsubmit`. Use [JavaScript event binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Learn about the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and its [`preventDefault` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: OK thank you. I removed the form tags and added 
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", createRow); 
to my script.